# Retrieving data from closed workbook using ADODB connection. Some data is skipped?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am currently writing some code that can access a separate workbook through an ADODB connection.  I have chosen this instead of other methods because of speed. Here is my code below:

```
    Sub GetWorksheetData(strSourceFile As String, strSQL As String, TargetCell As      range)
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, f As Integer, r As Long
    If TargetCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    On Error Resume Next
    cn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;ReadOnly=True;" & _
    "DBQ=" & strSourceFile & ";"
    ' DriverId=790: Excel 97/2000
    ' DriverId=22: Excel 5/95
    ' DriverId=278: Excel 4
    ' DriverId=534: Excel 3
    On Error GoTo 0
    If cn Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Can't find the file!", vbExclamation, ThisWorkbook.Name
    Exit Sub
    End If

    ' open a recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Open strSQL, cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
    ' rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]", _
    cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
    ' rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]", _
    cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    ' rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [SheetName$] WHERE [Field Name] LIKE 'A%'", _
    cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    ' rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [SheetName$] WHERE [Field Name] LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY [Field                 Name]", _
    cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

    ' optional ways of retrieving a recordset
    ' Set rs = cn.Execute("[A1:Z1000]") ' first worksheet
    ' Set rs = cn.Execute("[DefinedRangeName]") ' any worksheet

    On Error GoTo 0
    If rs Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Can't open the file!", vbExclamation, ThisWorkbook.Name
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
    End If

    'RS2WS rs, TargetCell
    TargetCell.CopyFromRecordset rs ' optional approach for Excel 2000 or later

    If rs.State = adStateOpen Then
    rs.Close
    End If
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Now, this code mostly works however when a row contains mixed data types, the query will skip some values.  For example:

Original data:

```
    3844774 12505604
    3844794 12505604
    4266113 3281271
    4295817 1307HX
```

Returned data:

```
    3844774 12505604
    3844794 12505604
    4266113 3281271
    4295817
```

Notice how the last bit of data is skipped.  This is true for multiple entries, but only those that contain letters (making it text).  The original table has everything set to text as well.  Any suggestions so that it doesn't skip these lines?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of `excel` are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because you are missing IMEX :)

See this link (**Section Treating data as text**)

http://connectionstrings.com/excel-2007

> Quote from that link.
>
> Treating data as text
>
> Use this one when you want to treat all data in the file as text, overriding Excels column type "General" to guess what type of data is in the column.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
```

> If you want to read the column headers into the result set (using HDR=NO even though there is a header) and the column data is numeric, use IMEX=1 to avoid crash.
>
> To always use IMEX=1 is a safer way to retrieve data for mixed data columns. Consider the scenario that one Excel file might work fine cause that file's data causes the driver to guess one data type while another file, containing other data, causes the driver to guess another data type. This can cause your app to crash.

For XLS files see this link

http://connectionstrings.com/excel

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to find the connection string for `XML spreadsheet 2003` but didn't find a clue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71696522/

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use this.

```
OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

> "IMEX=1;" tells the driver to always read "intermixed" (numbers,
>   dates, strings etc) data columns as text. Note that this option might
>   affect excel sheet write access negative.

[For more reading please read it.](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel)