# Print excel file without open it - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, printing

Now working on an Excel file, I found out how to print another worksheet from another workbook, but I need to open it before. Here is the code :

```
Workbooks.Open ("C:\...\myFile.xls")
Application.ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=2, Copies:=1, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

The problem is, my "mother file" is really huge. Open other files (might be a loop to open - now - and print 1X files makes it really long to calculate.

I'm looking for a code to print my excel files without open it.
Found some codes like "PrintOut" function or others but without open it, doesn't seems to work...

Anyone has an idea ?

Thank you for your help :)

Jerry

Comment: When a file is opened it's loaded into memory, the interface is displayed and at that time any workbook-specific calculations can take place.  Excel used to launch fast for versions 2010 and prior, but it's become significantly slower since. There are ways to open Excel files so they they are not seen by the user, but the file still needs to be loaded into memory before any printing can occur. If the file is large, there's not much you can do about that.  Besides getting a faster computer, the only thing I can think of is to turn off auto calculations, but I'm guessing you need those to print.

Comment: how about using a SQL query to pull data from closed workbook into current workbook and print that   ..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506223/retrieving-data-from-closed-workbook-using-adodb-connection-some-data-is-skippe#10506406

Comment: @TonyM Thank you for your prompt answer :) Could you indicate me the way to open files without display it please ?

Comment: @jsotola Will this solution also works with images that are contained in my close workbook please ? :)

Comment: For example, the 2nd answer on this page but setting appXL.Visible = False    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775969/open-specific-excel-file-in-new-instance-of-excel-when-file-is-opened

Comment: @TonyM Ok perfect thank you so much :)