# Consolidate data from closed workbook adodb connection approach

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that I am trying to consoldidate data using adodb connection approach, the excel files extension is xsl Excel 97 (or 2000)
This is my attempt

```
Sub MyTest()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, MovieFileName As String, MyFilesPath As String
    shTotal.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Clear
    MyFilesPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MyFolder\"
    MovieFileName = Dir(MyFilesPath & "*.xls")
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Do Until MovieFileName = ""
        cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & MyFilesPath & MovieFileName & ";" & "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
        cn.Open
        rs.Open Source:="SELECT * FROM [shTotal$] WHERE [Title] NOT LIKE '%twilight%'", ActiveConnection:=cn
        shTotal.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
        rs.Close
        cn.Close
        MovieFileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

But I got an error `External table is not in the expected format`
The error occurs at this line `cn.Open`

When I opened manually a file of the existing filesand tried to use save as option, I found the extension is XML spreadsheet 2003

Comment: Does this Microsoft knowledge base article help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/transfer-excel-data-from-ado-recordset

Comment: Maybe try different options from here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: You have to use the *sheetname* as visible in the excel frontend. Not the codename of the sheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried different options from the link you posted but the same problem. I have uploaded sample file in this link https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1375071-consolidate-data-from-closed-workbook-adodb-connection-approach.html

Comment: I'm not a member on that site so your attachment is not accessible

Comment: How can I upload a file here or what is the best uploading file that suits SO?